# Bind User Input from Text boxes to Collection of Objects via TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm relatively new to WPF and the MVVM architecture, as such I'm having issues with this data binding scenario.

I'm currently creating an application that allows users to create new People via a TabControl. When a user creates a new tab, it auto-populates with custom data fields such as First Name, Last Name, Age, etc. I then need to take this information, insert it into an ObservableCollection and use it to populate a WPF report (which I'm not having any issues with). I'm using a tab control so the user can go back and forth and edit the data as needed.

My issues is that only the first item in the tab control actually populates into the ObservableCollection. I have a button that creates a new tab, populates the content with a UserControl. I used the SelectedPerson so that I can go back in the list and access the Person that corresponds with the TabIndex that's currently being viewed so I can change/add/update the string information.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName}"/>
<TabControl ... SelectedIndex="{Binding PersonIndex} ... />
```

My Caregiver class is as follows:

```
public class Person{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And my C# code looks like:

```
private int _PersonIndex;
private Person _SelectedPerson;
private ObservableCollection<Person> Persons = new ObservableCollection<Persons>();

public void AddPerson (Person p){
   SelectedPerson = p;
   Persons.Add(p);
   PersonIndex = Persons.Count - 1;
}

public Person SelectedPerson {
   get {
      return _SelectedPerson;
   }
   set {
      _SelectedPerson = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
   }
}

public int PersonIndex{
   get {
      return _PersonIndex;
   }
   set {
      SelectedPerson = Persons[value];
      OnPropertyChanged("PersonIndex");
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You’re doing this backwards. Write a parent viewmodel that owns the ObservableCollection of tab item viewmodels. Bind the collection to the tab control’s ItemsSource. Give the parent viewmodel a command that creates a new tab item viewmodel and adds it to the ObservableCollection. That’s the easy way. That’s how WPF is meant to work, and it will make your life miserable if you fight it.

Comment: Thanks! I got that working no problem! But now is there a way to bind the textboxes in each tab so I can access their contents easily? I'm not exactly too sure how to do that...

Comment: You'll want to write a DataTemplate for `TabControl.ContentTemplate`. [Here's an overview on data templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).